# Dictionary function on an instance of a class

Tags: python, class, dictionary, magic-methods

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 'baz'
    def __len__(self):
        return 100
```

which yields the following when using the `len` magic method:

```
 >>> f = Foo()
 >>> len(f)
100
```

Is there a similar magic method for a dictionary

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 'baz'
    def __dict__(self):
        return dict(bar=self.bar)

 >>> f = Foo()
 >>> dict(f)
{'bar': 'baz'}
```

Comment: I believe you'd have to implement the iterator protocol, and yield a sequence of (key, value) pairs.  Or, have your class be a subclass of `dict`, with your contents stored as `self['bar'] = 'baz'` rather than as an instance attribute.

Comment: The container types do not have special hooks for conversion. Generally, most container type constructors accept arbitrary iterables as arguments. If it doesn't make sense to make your class iterable, just writing `to_dict` or `to_list` methods is perfectly acceptable. Note, for the numeric types, there are built-in hooks, `__int__`, `__float__` and `__complex__`.

Comment: Note, `dict` isn't a mere function, it is a *type*, a *class*, the class object of the `dict` instances.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's great -- thanks for clearing this up. I'll implement a `to_dict` method ... Thanks again!